# Why is Python 2.7 installed at root, unlike most programs today?

Tags: python, windows-7

Apologies for a likely stupid question, but no amount of Googling or searching here for my query could get me anywhere.

Just having issues with root installations lead me to wonder WHY Python 2.7 is naturally set up in the root directory of Windows, when everything else is in ProgramFiles?

Is there a simple answer for this I'm missing?

Comment: I have wondered about this myself. Ruby and a few other languages do this too. Good Question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comments in [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1284316) explain that the main problem is the space in “Program Files”.

> A long time ago, Python did install (by default) under "Program
>   Files".  I changed that, because of the endless problems created by
>   the frickin' embedded space, and rarer but subtler problems due to
>   "Program Files" not being a DOSish 8.3 name.  Overall I still think it
>   was a good change.
>
> Note that, unlike most Windows applications (which are GUI-based),
>   programming languages are *intended* to be used heavily from the
>   command line, invoked by scripts, and so on.  That's what makes a
>   space in the path endlessly error-prone.  In WinXP Pro, I noticed that
>   MS was still careful to put its own command-line/script tools
>   (sort.exe, ipconfig.exe, cscript.exe, ..., even notepad.exe) under
>   pure DOSish 8.3 space-free paths ;-)
>
> — Tim Peters

Comment: Does that mean it used to be difficult/impossible to do commands in DOS using names with spaces?

Comment: It was not supported, but there was a workaround. Have you ever seen paths like `C:\PROGRA~1\`? ;)

Comment: I've seen it but never had to use it, so I don't understand it. What's the significance?

Apologies, I never had a formal training in command line stuff, just been picked up over years of coding, but nothing very old. /noob

Comment: I should add that I've been installing Python to “Program Files” on Windows for a few years and I never had an issue with that.

Comment: How incredibly interesting, insightful info and link, thanks!

Comment: FWIW I've been installing it in `E:\Program Files\Python` for many years without any major problems. On the infrequent occasions I actually have to type the full path to it to something in the folder, I just remember to put quotes around it. No big deal.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure 7 can handle the whitespace, and even though I'm an admin on my work machine, installing anything to C:\Python27 is bloody nightmare.

Comment: That, not to say that "Program Files"  can get different names in different Windows versions - it is ok, if your porgram is called b y cheking the windows registry - a nightmare otherwise.

Comment: @Befall The problem is not Win7, but developers who occasionally assume that paths do not contain spaces and so they do bas thinks like omitting quotes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well as Tim Peters explained it's because of the whitespace/null space or embedded space in the path. If ever you've used an older windows version and tried cd'in to a path such as documents and settings you'd get an error saying 'documents' not recognized blah blah.. that's because it thinks documents is a directory, and is a directory, and files is  a directory because of the blank spaces in it's path name. I found enclosing it in " " quotation marks bound it as a single string rather than three separate strings. Same rules applied to Python when errors occurred trying to access the path, so the simplest solution was to put it's path in an area where there are no null spaces, such as C:\Python, and not C:\Program Files\Python.
Yet again as stated above, those Windows tools mentioned are all in paths without white spaces such as C:\Windows or C:\Windows\system32. Just helps not to have space when setting the path in the global path variable because it's less error prone when utilities in the path specified are utilized. -k0r8i05